# Delete number after slash in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey lets say I have url like this:

```
http://google.com/1/2
```

How do I delete last number(after last slash character)? all numbers can vary in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var URL = "http://google.com/1/2";
var newUrl = URL.substring(0, URL.lastIndexOf('/'));
console.log(newUrl);
```